# Find third <td> within <tr> using bs4 soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use bs4 to return the value of a  from a string name found within an

For example, in the below html, I'm passing through "linktext" as self.variable, and wish to return the results in the third (and last)  of 12345

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">linktext</a>
    </td>
    <td width="10"></td>
    <td>12345</td>
</tr>
```

My Python code:

```
class Scraper(Scrape):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scraper, self).__init__()
        self.headers = ("Variable", "Result")

    def run(self, inputs, mode, variable):
        self.variable = variable
        if mode == 1:
            self.get_data("https://testurl.com" + {mode}, 10, inputs)
        else:
            self.get_data("https://testurl.com" + "nope" + {mode}, 10, inputs)

    def parse(self, soup):
        total = soup.find(string=re.compile(self.variable)).parent.next_sibling
        return total.string.strip()
```

This code works, but returns the result of the second sibling (the td with a width). I've tried appending another next_sibling however it doesn't return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `linktext`'s parent (the `<tr>`) using the [`find_parent()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) method, and then get the last `td` using the [`last-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp) CSS selector (finds the last child of its parent).

To use a CSS selector use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of `.find()`.

In your case:

```
total = soup.find(string=re.compile(self.variable)).find_parent("tr").select_one("td:last-of-type").text
```

---

Here is a working example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">linktext</a>
    </td>
    <td width="10"></td>
    <td>12345</td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
total = (
    soup.find(string=re.compile(r"linktext"))
    .find_parent("tr")
    .select_one("td:last-of-type")
    .text
)

print(total)
```

Output:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` and `:-soup-contains()`, (`:contains` with earlier `soupsieve` installs, to isolate the `tr` having the child `td`, with the `a` containing the target string. Then move to the last `td` with `:last-of-type`.

You can pass in the variable with an f-string:

```
soup.select_one(f'tr:has(td > a:-soup-contains("{self.variable}")) td:last-of-type').text
```

Example:

```
html = '''<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">linktext</a>
    </td>
    <td width="10"></td>
    <td>12345</td>
</tr>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
var = 'linktext'
print(soup.select_one(f'tr:has(td > a:-soup-contains("{var}")) td:last-of-type').text)
```